# Recursion - incrementing a number and returning

Tags: java, recursion

Ok, this must be something really stupid....my statement is returning 2:

- When I print out the values they are all correct
- The return statement is wrong somehow

Code:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    System.out.println(countToTen(1));
}

public static int countToTen(int last_answer){
    last_answer++;
    if(last_answer != 10){
        countToTen(last_answer);
    }
    return  last_answer;
}
```

Comment: Hint: you're not doing anything with the return value of `countToTen` when you call it recursively...

Comment: thank you Mark, so why must i do it that way? Please post this answer so i can give you credit

Comment: Well, try either debugging through the code or just *think* about what it's going to return...

Comment: You are not passing the argument by reference, it is a copy. You are doing a modification in last_answer in the context of method, but this change is not propagate outside, because in the end you return last_answer++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing your `if` statement with:

```
if(last_answer != 10){
    return countToTen(last_answer);
}
```

Without the `return` statement, the recursive calls do get executed, but the calculated result is never returned.

The order of calls with your broken code looks like:

```
countToTen(1)
 -> countToTen(2)
 -->  countToTen(3)
 ---> more calls to countToTen()
 --- ... --> countToTen(10) // do nothing, and return to the top-level method call
 -> return 2 // 2 because you incremented it using lastAnswer++
```

Comment: So why is "return" neccessary, and could you please post it inside your answer for others! Thanks :)

Comment: Very good, please up this question for future viewers. I marked it as the answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns the value from the first call. It is the initial value (1) incremented once by the ++ statement, so the function returns 2.

Integers are passed by value in Java, incrementing the passed value inside the function does not change the value outside:

```
int x = 0;
v(x);
// x still 0 here.

void v(int x) {
  x = 100;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    System.out.println(countToTen(1));    
}

public static int countToTen(int last_answer)
{    
    last_answer++;

    if(last_answer != 10)
    {
        return countToTen(last_answer); //Here was the error
    }

    return  last_answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int countToTen(int last_answer){

  last_answer++;

  if(last_answer != 10){
    return countToTen(last_answer);
  }
  else {
    return last_answer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats the same thing except now it wont compile now because there isn't a mandatory return.

Comment: It will compile.  All code paths return a value (there is no code path which bypasses both of Tyler's return statements).  Some people prefer `if(condition){return value;} else {return othervalue;}` over `if(condition){return value;} return othervalue;`, as it makes it more obvious that `return othervalue;` only happens if `condition` is false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out 1,2,3,4 ... 10, you need to print out the answer in every phase separately

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    countToTen(1);
}

public static void countToTen(int last_answer){

    System.out.println(last_answer);
    last_answer++;

    if(last_answer <= 10){
    countToTen(last_answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sarah, no i was just wondering why my ending return was 2 and not 10

Answer (score 0):

My proposal

```
public static int countToTen(int last_answer){

   last_answer++;

    if(last_answer < 10){
        return countToTen(last_answer);
    } else {
        return last_answer;
    }
}
```

You are not passing the argument by reference, it is a copy. You are doing a modification in last_answer in the context of method, but this change is not propagate outside, because in the end you return last_answer++